# Apache FOP - Arial

Tags: java, apache-fop

I updated to the newest version of Apache FOP, because I've read the support of fonts has been improved.

Here is my configuration file (fop.xconf):

```
<fop version="1.0">

    <!-- Strict user configuration -->
    <strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>

    <!-- Base URL for resolving relative URLs -->
    <base>./</base>

    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
        <fonts>
             <auto-detect/>
        </fonts>
    </renderer>
</fop>
```

which I use in the code:

```
private String configurationFile = "/fop/fop.xconf";
    ...
    Fop fop = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(getClass().getResource(configurationFile).toURI()))
                        .newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, pdfoutStream);
```

However, when I define Arial in the .xsl File

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt">
```

I only get the following warning: `Font "Arial,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".`

Am I missing/not seeing anything? I've tried to add a font-metric instead of using `<auto-detect/>`, but to no avail. Arial is an available font on my system.

Edit: Thanks, the duplicate thread was what I was seeking for! The way I configured the configuration file was incorrect.